# Is this an exploit? What is the drawback

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I got an imperial administration law and can revoke dutchies without upsetting vassals.

Once I had a debt and one of my counts offered to by a dutchy title for 200 gold. I sold that, and few seconds later revoked dutchy. That vassal got +60 for granting dutch, and -60 for revoking ducthy, other vassals are not concerned... and I got 200 gold...

Free money? Do I miss something bad happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the opinions time out at the same time, yes, "free" money **for you**.

Note that vassals *do* spend the money they accrue on improving their holdings, so your realm *as a whole* didn't change wealth. It's not an exploit.

Comment: And you can't demand from the vassal to buy the title. It's not an exploit if you're limited in the ability to activate it at will

Comment: But any time they are interested to buy a title - I'm going to sell it.
The fact that these money vassal could spend on buildings is good, but at a particular moment of time, the empire might benefit more by spending these money in other places (raise the opinion of the Pope and help to remove excommunication, for instance).

Comment: Often negative opinion modifiers last longer than positive ones, so you should check to confirm they do time out at the same time.